# How do I stop the screen from flickering when drawing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Here's my code:

```
public class Game extends JComponent implements Runnable {

    World w = null;
    Keyboard keyboard = null;

    Thread game = null;

    /** The constructor. I would like to initialize here */
    public Game(){
        // Create and set up the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Game");
        frame.setSize(500, 700);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        world = new World();
        keyboard = new KeyBoard(this);
        game = new Thread(this);
        game.start();
    }

    /** The run() method. I'll be using it as a game loop */
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // I don't want to do anything
            }
        }
    }

    /** I was doing a test draw here, but getting an error */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
    }

}
```

The screen is flickering frequently. I tried changing the value in the call for `sleep()` in the run method but it doesn't solve the problem.

How do I stop the screen from flickering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The screen is flickering frequently.

A classic sign of doing things like sleeping on the EDT.  That is not the way to do custom painting.  Use a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to invoke `repaint()`.

See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) & also [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) in the tutorial.

Comment: I think than using it, could you say how to use System.nanoTime() or System.getCurrentTimeMillis()

Comment: (polite cough) - all correct, of course, but not the best of ideas to repeat the incorrect code, IMO :-)

Comment: @kleopatra  Point taken, edited to *"..sleeping on the EDT"*.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Could you plz suggest me a good tutorial in making games with tile-based collision detection?

Comment: I've never dealt with 'tile-based collision', so your Google is as good as mine.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add a child of JPanel doing the drawing. This is has by default setDoubleBuffered(true), so no flickering. Do the painting there.

That hint of Andrew Thompson about the timer is even more important.